# does std::runtime_error copy the string passed in the constructor?

Tags: c++, exception

I wonder if this line creates a dangling pointer:

```
string arg="derp";
throw std::runtime_error("Unknown argument "+arg);
```

Does `std::runtime_error` copy the `string`, or does it store the reference?

Comment: Your title says `std::exception` but the code is `std::runtime_error`. Note that `std::runtime_error` is the exception class that takes a message, as you're doing, but `std::exception` does not, so the title doesn't make too much sense (i.e., `std::exception` doesn't *have* a string-accepting constructor).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::exception` (which `std::runtime_error` inherits from) must make a copy of the message, even if that's not called out in the standard explicitly (that I can find).  There's no reason for the `exception` class to expect that the source of the `what()` message will outlive it in the general case.

Comment: +1; all the objects in local scope will be destroyed when the exception is thrown so there's no way you could access basically anything but string literals if it didn't make a copy.

Comment: Also don't forget that an exception object can be created and kept around (and never thrown). One of those exception objects  still needs to be a valid object with the same message even if the string passed into it is destroyed or changed.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Where is that exactly stated, though? (Obviously into pedant land now, but I'm curious.) All that's stated is that after construction of a `std::runtime_error` by a `std::string` named `what_arg`, `std::strcmp(what(), what_arg.c_str()) == 0`. It doesn't say anything about copies of said exception object.

Comment: @GManNickG: I don't see anything about it explicitly stated, but for `exception::what()` to work in the face of code such as `string* s = new string("foobar"); runtime_error rte(*s); delete s;cout << rte.what();` a copy would have to be made.

Comment: I believe the lack of specificity is deliberate to allow the implementation as much flexibility as possible. What happens behind the scene is not that important as long as the constrains are achieved. I think the important thing to note is that a string passed to the constructor will be reflected in a call to what at some later point.

Answer (score 1):

it takes a string refrence. And passes that to the catch block as a reference, however if you pass a string litterial into the constructor it will  create a temp string object. Also, do not do + arg with a string litterial, that's a syntax error.

Comment: it is not. There's an operator+ overload that allows it.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone there is no operator + on type const char* .

Comment: @LorenzoPistone std::string has operator + , const char* does not.

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator+/ third overload. After this, I run out of arguments to persuade you.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone furthermore sir, your code post did not show a type for arg.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone there ya go ;)

Comment: Yeah, you can overload operators on basic types as long as at least one argument to the operator is a user-defined type (that means the user-defined type could be the second _or_ first argument).

Comment: @SethCarnegie he didn't originally have his type posted in his code post, hence the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the pointer? You are copying a string literal and implicitly casting it to `const std::string&` when constructing the runtime error.

Comment: the point is: does runtime_error store the reference (sorry for calling it a pointer) to the temporary object that I'm constructing, or does it copy it (which is what I hope)?

Comment: I agree with GMan. I'm pretty sure it has to make a copy as the scope of the catch block can be outside the scope of the temporary you're passing. It will work but how the compiler will actually boil it down may differ occasionally.